# Angularjs form is readonly. Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How I define my app in html:

```
<div ng-app="md-app">
    <div id="general">
        <ng-include src="template1" ng-controller="GeneralCtrl"></ng-include>
    </div>
</div>
```

The js to fetch a person from rest and set template:

```
function GeneralCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.template1 = 'some_path';

    $scope.person = $http.get('route', {id: personId})).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
    }); 
}
```

In the template I can read all data. I have a form to edit some data of the person, however the form is readonly by default:

```
 <form>
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="person.nick"/>
     </div>
 </form>
```

The nickname of the person is displayed in the input field, but I cannot edit it. When I start typing it is just ignored. Why?

Comment: Try using .success() instead of .then()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$http.get doesn't return data to your model, as it is asynchronous. It returns the Promise object. You need to assign the resulting value to $scope.person in the .success() callback:

```
$scope.person = {};
$http.get('route', {id: personId})).success(function(response){
    $scope.person = response.data;
});
```

Please see the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) for $http with examples